# JDBC oracle stored procedure update count is -1

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

Oracle 11g, Java 8, ojdbc8

stored procedure with OUT REF_CURSOR, e.g.,

```
create or replace procedure foo(employeeId IN number, c OUT SYS_REFCURSOR) AS
BEGIN
    open c for select * from Employee where id = employeeId;
    update Employee set name='New Name" where id= employeeId;
END;
```

JDBC call the procedure:

```
CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("{call foo(?,?)}");
statement.setObject(1, 100);
statement.registerOutParameter(2, oracle.jdbc.OracleTupes.CURSOR);
statement.execute();

int count = statement.getUpdateCount(); // error: return -1
assertEquals(1, count);
```

The update count should be 1, but it is -1.

Comment: What is the result of `execute()`? `true` or `false`?

Comment: execute() return false.

Comment: I'm not sure if Oracle even communicates update counts from within a stored procedure. What happens if you use `getMoreResults()` followed by `getUpdateCount()`?